# Performance and information JSP compilation and runtimes (websphere, tomcat)

Tags: jsp, tomcat, websphere

Does anyone have any information on the performance of JSP runtimes.  I haven't found any statistics on them.

For example,are there any performance or memory issues with how I use jsp includes or EL expressions, which ones should I stay away from.  Does tomcat have any issues?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any statistics or information to point you toward. However, I can tell you that I am currently working on a web app running on Tomcat 6.x in which we are using both jsp includes and EL expressions and we have not encountered any performance or memory related issues. I am not aware of any besides.